# What happens if a read occurs before an update is propagated to all replicas in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I know the answer is Tunable Consistency. But can anyone elaborate me with example. I could not find what a real time scenario could be. Before implementing into project. Plz explain in both...for single cluster and for multi-cluster

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you meant by multi-cluster. So, I will answer for single cluster.

Let's say, you have a C* cluster with 5 nodes and your replication factor is 5(edited from 1 - after a comment).

Current state is (x1,y1)

You have two operations
update(x1,y2)
read (x1)

Now for different consistency level pattern,

1. READ QUORUM, WRITE QUORUM: 
   You always read from at least 3 nodes and always write to at least 3 nodes.
   So you will never read old data.
2. READ ONE, WRITE QUORUM:
   You always read from 1 node and always write to at least 3 nodes.
   So you have 2/5 chance that you read old data.
3. READ ONE, WRITE ONE:
   You always read from 1 node and always write to at least 1 node.
   So you have 4/5 chance that you read old data.

For more pattern you can check this wonderful tool.
http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

Hope it helps!

Comment: "your replication factor is 1" -- did you mean to specify RF=5?

Comment: Plz understand what I asked. What happpens when an update is going on and the read occurs. Suppose I have 3 nodes. node 1 is update node2 update is going on, and that time itself a read is called. Which data will it return? From node1 or node2 or node3. Lets say consistency level is Read One, Write all.

Comment: @PritamPrakash try to understand his answer then. He told you that to ensure that the information is correct, you must set a higher level of consistency which means checking the information on more nodes. If the consistency level is read one, write all, cassandra will just return the information from the first querried node. if it is read all, it will return the last update by comparing all the value on each nodes

Comment: @PritamPrakash Sorry that you haven't grasped from my explanation.

In your example with 3 nodes, READ level ONE and RF 3, it means that there are 3 nodes having the data that you requested for.

If the client driver chose node 1 you get back y2, if it were node 2 or node 3 you get back y1. The driver doesn't complain and return's back as you requested CL ONE.

If your consistency level was TWO, then your driver will return y1. It will have to get the same result from at least 2 copies .

If requested for CL ALL, you will get an error.

Comment: @chaitan64arun So what do I do... My requirement is to get the most updated node when queried even when only one node is updated. Please provide me a solution.I want to get the result of the most updated node even if only one node is updated.